# How does one get the object in a python object inside a decorated function without going into a recursion error?

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators

I have this code:

```
    @property
    def cls(self):
        assert getattr(self, 'cls') is self.classifier  # idk why this one goes into a recursion death but the other doesn't
        return self.classifier

    @cls.setter
    def cls(self, new_cls):
        # assert getattr(self, 'cls') is self.classifier
        self.classifier = new_cls
        setattr(self, 'cls', self.classifier)
        # self.cls = self.classifier  # CALLS THIS FUNCTION RECURSIVELY AND KILLS YOUR PROGRAM
        # assert getattr(self, 'cls') is self.classifier
```

The invariant I want is that self.cls and self.classifier are the same object. When I try to enforce that in the decorators I get recursion deaths.

What puzzles me is that the `setattr` does not cause a recusion death while the `getattr` does. Why is that?

I understand that when `.cls` or `.cls = new_cls` that the code actually calls my decorators so it makes sense it would go into a recursion death. I tried to go around it by calling python's `getattr` and `setattr`. One seems to work but the other does not. Why?

error:

```
getattr(self, 'cls')
...
  [Previous line repeated 484 more times]
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

Comment: `getattr(self, 'cls')` invokes the property getter, just like `self.cls` does. So you recurse infinitely.

Comment: Please include enough code to actually reproduce the behavior.  I put together a quick example and I did see infinite recursion when I tried to call a setter that sets its own property via `setattr`, so I suspect you're never actually calling that setter in your code.

Comment: Why do you need to "enforce" this? The `@property` decorator ensures it.

Comment: Can't reproduce. Using `setattr` on the property in it's own setter _does_ lead to  recursion error for me.

Comment: Like Barmar said, it's not at all clear what you're trying to accomplish here. Your code is akin to writing `def one(): assert one() == 1; return 1`

Answer (score 1):

The way to write this code to do what you want it to do is simply:

```
    @property
    def cls(self):
        return self.classifier

    @cls.setter
    def cls(self, new_cls):
        self.classifier = new_cls
```

`self.cls` is now by definition always the same as the `self.classifier` attribute, and `self.classifier` can be set by setting `self.cls`.  There's no need for any recursion.

If `self.classifier` needs to *itself* be a property rather than a normal attribute, you'd handle this by having both `self.cls` and `self.classifier` reference a private attribute, e.g. `self._classifier`.  It is not possible to define a property solely in terms of itself.